# JS modules: How implement sort of an interface?

Tags: javascript, interface, module

I'm working with JS modules bundled with Webpack.

Suppose I have a common module, used everywhere. This module require another module, let's say it is an output for errors

```
var err = require("./errors.js");

var common = {
    doSomething: function() {
        var a = 1;
        if (a == 1) {
            err.output('An error occured');
        }
    }
}

module.exports = common;
```

Now this error management module could be somthing like

```
var $ = require("jquery");

var errors = {
    output: function(msg) {
        $('<div class="someClass">'+msg+'</div>).appendTo('body');
    }
}

module.exports = errors;
```

And finally I have my entry point:

```
var common = require("./common.js");

common.doSomething();
```

My question is: since I have got two applications, let's call them backend and frontend, I would like different implementation of errors.output, because it's view-bounded. Maybe in backend I want to use a class different from "someClass", or maybe I don't want to use a DIV, but a P, or else.

I have multi entry points, actually. So I wouldn't like to have each of them passing around lots of callbacks or configuration. I would like to have only one implementation of errors module for all the entry point of the backend and only one for all the entry point of the frontend, without any code repetition.

This is something that I would implement with interface, in PHP.
Which is the best approach for Javascript?

Thank you

Comment: Even if you had an interface in PHP you'd still have to define each implementation that worked differently. Isn't that kind of the same as passing around configuration? What is your goal exactly? Are you looking to assure that certain functions have been defined?

Comment: Unfortunately I have got plenty entry points. Let's say one hundred. So i would like that 50 of them would work with error-implementation-1.js, and the other 50 would work with error-implementation-2.js. So that all the code is in those 2 files, without repetition. But I don't know how to achieve that. I need that common is able to plug/unplug one implementation, rather than another,

Comment: You could require both types of errors in common, and then when you require common, pass in a config value you can use to determine which error type?

Comment: This would not be efficient, because webpack would bundle always both backend and frontend code, even when not required (Consider that "error" example mod is just an example, there would be dozens of them).
I came to a solution: every "interface" module comes with a set of default values and default callbacks, that can be overwritten throur an init() method. Then I write a new (single) module for backend, which contains the values and callbacks to overwrite and call this init() method. same for frontend.
Then every entry points require this new module.